# PyQt fractional scaling

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've built a Qt Application in my 21" monitor, so all the window sizes and font sizes are perfect for monitor of this size. When I tried to run the application in smaller displays the text inside labels got cut-off and broken. So I set `os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"`. But now the problem is the UI is super huge in these small displays.

Is there any way I can scale my application by a fraction to match displays ?

I used Qt Designer to create the UI's. Here is a sample UI.

```
self.setObjectName("Dialog")
self.setFixedSize(470, 138)
self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 131, 16))
self.label.setObjectName("label")
self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 281, 22))
self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 90, 75, 23))
self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Re. `"When I tried to run the application in smaller displays the text inside labels got cut-off and broken"`: it sounds like you are either fixing the sizes of various elements or not using layouts correctly -- or perhaps both.  Please show some code to provide context -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I've added an example. @G.M.

Comment: Calling `setFixedSize`, `setGeometry` etc. in this way is almost always the wrong thing to do -- it expressly forbids the scaling behaviour you are looking for.  Use [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) to manage the geometry instead.